# How to control form action depending on condition in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, submit, form-submit

I am having a form in PHP. I used both `onclick` and `onsubmit` to call a javascript function.
On `onclick` i have called the `rangeValidator()` and `onsubmit` i have called `formValidator()`. I am checking the condition and if that is true then it is redirecting to the page which in `form action`.

Code:

```
<form action="javascript:check();" name="frm" id="frm" onsubmit="return formValidator()">
.....
     <input type="submit" onclick="return rangeValidator()">
</form>
```

Javascript function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function rangeValidator()
{
   ......
}

function formValidator()
{
    var s=confirm("Are you sure about all the filled in details?");

    if(s==true)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now what i want is that, On submit it should check above condition, if that condition is true i want to check the other condition & respectively it should redirect to the page depending on true or false i.e. I want to change the action of the form to two of pages depending on value true or false of `condition()` function.

To change the action I have coded as below.

```
function check()
{
    if(confirm('Do you want to see PF share?'))
    {
        url='add_sal_success.php';
        document.addsalsuccess.action = url;
    }
    else
    {   
                url='add_sal_success_wo.php';
            document.addsalsuccess.action = url;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you need to execute `rangeValidator()` every time before the form is submitted, you may have to add it to the form's event handler too, as somebody can simply hit enter on an input field and the `onclick` handler is never fired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this
use only `onsubmit="return check()"`

Based on you condition you can set the action

```
function check()
{
    var f = document.getElementById("frm");
     f.setAttribute('method',"post");
    if(confirm('Do you want to see PF share?'))
    {

         f.setAttribute('action',"yourpage.php");
    }
    else
    {   

         f.setAttribute('action',"yourANOTHERpage.php");
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: If you call both, any one of function returning false in any case then form will not get submitted

Comment: can you post on which condition you want to send form to which page,
you can do all in single function call

Comment: what should i give in form action?

Comment: url of page where you want to submit it

Comment: i have changed function call in onsubmit to return check(); then it is working but i want to check those conditions in formValidator function also.. i have already passed one function in onclick so how can i check that formValidator function.?'

Comment: You can add form validator code in check function above all these,
if validation is failed return false